# Task.WhenAll() only executes 2 threads at a time?

Tags: c#, caching, locking, task, semaphore

In this problem I am trying to cache a single value, let's call it foo. If the value is not cached, then it takes while to retrieve.

My problem is not **implementing** it, but **testing** it.

In order to test it, I fire off 5 simultaneous tasks using Task.WhenAll() to get the cached value. The first one enters the lock and retrieves the value asynchronously, while the other 4 threads **should** wait on the lock. After waiting, they should one by one re-check the cached value, find that it has been retrieved by the first thread that cached it, and return it without a second retrieval.

```
[TestClass]
public class Class2
{
    private readonly Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

    private bool? foo;

    private async Task<bool> GetFoo()
    {
        bool fooValue;

        // Atomic operation to get current foo
        bool? currentFoo = this.foo;

        if (currentFoo.HasValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo already retrieved");
            fooValue = currentFoo.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            {
                // Atomic operation to get current foo
                currentFoo = this.foo;

                if (currentFoo.HasValue)
                {
                    // Foo was retrieved while waiting
                    Console.WriteLine("Foo retrieved while waiting");
                    fooValue = currentFoo.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Simulate waiting to get foo value
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting new foo");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    this.foo = true;
                    fooValue = true;
                }
            }
            semaphore.Release();
        }

        return fooValue;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        Task[] getFooTasks = new[] {
            this.GetFoo(),
            this.GetFoo(),
            this.GetFoo(),
            this.GetFoo(),
            this.GetFoo(),
        };
        await Task.WhenAll(getFooTasks);
    }
}
```

In my actual test and production code, I am retrieving the value through an interface and mocking that interface using Moq. At the end of the test I verify that the interface was only called 1 time (pass), rather than > 1 time (failure).

Output:

```
Getting new foo
Foo retrieved while waiting
Foo already retrieved
Foo already retrieved
Foo already retrieved
```

However you can see from the output of the test that it isn't as I expect. It looks as though **only 2 of the threads executed concurrently**, while the other threads waited until the first two were completed to even **enter** the GetFoo() method.

Why is this happening? Is it because I'm running it inside a VS unit test? Note that my test still passes, but not in the way I expect it to. I suspect there is some restriction on the number of threads in a VS unit test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll()` doesn't *start* the tasks - it just *waits* for them.

Likewise, calling an `async` method doesn't actually force parallelization - it doesn't introduce a new thread, or anything like that. You only get new threads if:

- You await something which hasn't completed, and your synchronization context schedules the continuation on a new thread (which it won't do in a WinForms context, for example; it'll just reuse the UI thread)
- You explicitly use `Task.Run`, and the task scheduler creates a new thread to run it. (It may not need to, of course.)
- You explicitly start a new thread.

To be honest, the use of *blocking* `Semaphore` methods in an async method feels very wrong to me. You don't seem to be really embracing the idea of asynchrony... I haven't tried to analyze *exactly* what your code is going to do, but I think you need to read up more on how `async` works, and how to best use it.

Comment: This (calling an async method doesn't actually force parallelization) makes sense to me... I am using semaphore to get around the inability to use await in a lock() block, and I understand that it is a bad thing to do because of potential deadlock. I will look into other solutions. But this at least explains to me why the test wasn't executing as expected. Looks like the test will work fine if I get the implementation correct.

Comment: So what is the preferred model for using await in a lock()?

Comment: @user3339997: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to lay with `semaphore.WaitOne()`

An `async` method will run **synchronously** until it hits its first `await`. In your code, the first `await` is only after the `WaitOne` is signaled. The fact that a method is `async` certainly does not mean it runs on multiple threads, it usually means the opposite.

Do get around this, use [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805(v=vs.110).aspx) that way the calling thread will yield control until the semaphore signals its done

```
public class Class2
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private bool? foo;

    private async Task<bool> GetFoo()
    {
        bool fooValue;

        // Atomic operation to get current foo
        bool? currentFoo = this.foo;

        if (currentFoo.HasValue)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Foo already retrieved");
           fooValue = currentFoo.Value;
        }
       else
       {
           await semaphore.WaitAsync();
           {
               // Atomic operation to get current foo
               currentFoo = this.foo;

               if (currentFoo.HasValue)
               {
                  // Foo was retrieved while waiting
                   Console.WriteLine("Foo retrieved while waiting");
                   fooValue = currentFoo.Value;
               }
              else
              {
                  // Simulate waiting to get foo value
                  Console.WriteLine("Getting new foo");
                  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                  this.foo = true;
                  fooValue = true;
              }
          }
        semaphore.Release();
    }

    return fooValue;
}
```

Comment: You marked johns answer as the solution, it didn't provide you a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think his answer is slightly more correct because it doesn't involve using await within the semaphore. He provided a link to an answer of how to properly lock within an await, and provided more background on my problem. Your answer was useful too, so I upvoted.

Comment: He provided a link to `AsyncLock`, which isn't that different from awaiting on `SemaphoreSlim`. He talks in his answer about not using a *blocking* semaphore. Anyway, you're free to choose whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
> ```

This should allow other tasks to run, but I suspect they are blocked on:

> ```
> semaphore.WaitOne();
> ```

Mixing concurrency styles (in this case using Tasks and manual control with a synchronisation object) is very hard to get right.

(You seem to be trying to get the same value by having multiple concurrent tasks all pooling: this seems overkill.)

By default .NET will limit `Task` concurrency to the number of (logical) CPU Cores available, I suspect your system has two.